# Merge Two RACSignals, Complete on First Completion

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have two `RACSignal`s one of which is a timer and the other one indicates there's work to do. Since the work indication is sometimes unreliable, there's the timer, which takes care that work will be done periodically if the precise notifications don't work.

The general setup is:

```
    RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal merge:@[
                         [[RACSignal interval:0.5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]]
                           filter:^BOOL(__unused id _x) {
                               return isThereAProblemInDeliveringWork();
                           }],
                         incomingWorkSubject
                         ]];
```

Now I want `signal` to complete as soon as `incomingWorkSubject` was completed. So, in general: Complete the merged signal as soon as any of its input signals completed. Unfortunately, `[RACSignal merge:...]` doesn't do what I want and apparently waits for all incoming signals to complete.

What would be the ReactiveCocoa-way of achieving that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious approach is to apply [`-takeUntil:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h#L270-275), which completes a signal when a supplied signal either sends a value, or completes. Since you only want completion when `incomingWorkSubject` completes, and not when it sends a value, use [`-ignoreValues`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h#L481-485).

I've extracted the timer signal to a variable for readability.

```
RACSignal *timer = [[RACSignal
    interval:0.5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]]
    filter:^BOOL(__unused id _x) {
        return isThereAProblemInDeliveringWork();
    }];

RACSignal *signal = [[RACSignal
    merge:@[ incomingWorkSubject, timer ]]
    takeUntil:[incomingWorkSubject ignoreValues]];
```

For the sake of discussion, there's another way of going about this that might fit the bill. Instead, using the `timer` defined above, take samples of `incomingWorkSubject` using [`-sample:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h#L473-479). How you do this depends on the nature of `incomingWorkSubject`. If it's a `RACReplaySubject`, and you know a value will be available, it can be sampled directly.

```
RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal merge:@[
    incomingWorkSubject,
    [incomingWorkSubject sample:timer]
]];
```

However, if `incomingWorkSubject` is a vanilla `RACSubject`, then you'll need to compose a new signal to include an initial value, with [`-startWith:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/f9bc1fd2c58e0c5f9096a1c42d3e51d9c912d4e0/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h#L172-174), so that `-sample:` has a value to send when `timer` fires.

```
RACSignal *signal = [RACSignal merge:@[
    incomingWorkSubject,
    [[incomingWorkSubject startWith:initialValue] sample:timer]
]];
```

In english, this creates a signal that sends the latest value from `incomingWorkSubject`, and also will send a recent cached value from `incomingWorkSubject`, but only when a periodic check to `isThereAProblemInDeliveringWork()` is affirmative. The merged signal completes when `incomingWorkSubject` completes.

Comment: I wouldn't use `-sample:` unless you care about the actual values of `incomingWorkSubject` (which doesn't seem to be the case).